# Ubuntu 20.04 is not loading after cancelling "resetter" in progress

Tags: 20.04, system-installation, recovery-mode

I was using resetter to reset my PC. It showed some error while resetting so I had to cancel it. I cancelled it in the middle of the operation. It deleted some important folders. I could not open the terminal or any folders, so I had no option but to reboot.

Now i can't open it. In recovery mode, menu options are not showing and entering my login password results in an incorrect password message. I have no idea what to do. Are there any suggestions on how to open my laptop?

Comment: The only thing I can find about "resetter" is an [abandoned GitHub project](https://github.com/gaining/Resetter). It seems like the purpose of this script is to essentially restore your system to the state of a new installation. Looking at what it was supposed to do, there's no surprise that interrupting it halfway resulted in a broken system. I would not let a project like this anywhere near my PC no matter what it purports to do, especially an abandoned project. Why would you not just reinstall? Well now, you will probably need to reinstall the OS anyway and restore your data from backups.

Answer (score 1):

#### NO, you cannot recover this

As [Nmath](https://askubuntu.com/users/953371/nmath) mentioned in [their comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1387221/ubuntu-20-04-is-not-loading-after-cancelling-resetter-in-progress#comment2395183_1387221):

> The only thing I can find about "resetter" is an abandoned GitHub
> project. It seems like the purpose of this script is to essentially
> restore your system to the state of a new installation. Looking at
> what it was supposed to do, there's no surprise that interrupting it
> halfway resulted in a broken system. I would not let a project like
> this anywhere near my PC no matter what it purports to do, especially
> an abandoned project. Why would you not just reinstall? Well now, you
> will probably need to reinstall the OS anyway and restore your data
> from backups.

There is no way to recover this mess. This project is deprecated and is no longer maintained. As, you can see on its [GitHub page](https://github.com/gaining/Resetter), they've removed everything from the README file. This indicates that they don't want anyone to use this script again. I can see that they have removed a lot of essential files too.

Now, the source code of the project cannot find those essential directories. If you go to [this page](https://github.com/gaining/Resetter/tree/master/Resetter), you'll find only `/usr` and `/etc/sudoers` files are there. This means that the script couldn't find `/var` and a few more essential directories including `/boot`. Apparently `/boot` is still there, but there is no information about kernel and memtest, making your system unbootable. The source code of the script has clearly removed everything from your system *(except a few things)*. **Reinstalling is the only option**.